# Make file extension downloadable

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing an application that is going to import `.xyz` files from the Internet. I know that by adding to AndroidManifest.xml something like:

```
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz" />
          </intent-filter>
```

I can offer the user a choice whether he wants to open `.xyz` files through my application or in the browser whenever he clicks on a link to such a file.

Using:

```
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.xyz" />
          </intent-filter>
```

I can let the user have a similar choice when browsing through his local files.

I want Android (not my application) to download any such files from the web, and only give the user the choice to open the local files from his file explorer. However, when I omit the first code block and only use the second, my downloads fail because Android thinks there is no app that can handle `.xyz` files. Any pointers?

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not supported by all browsers. Also, I *strongly* encourage you to switch to a solution based upon a MIME type rather than a file extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought this is an OS limitation - my downloads actually start (I get those small downward-pointing arrows in the phone status bar), they just fail before anything is downloaded. But will take a closer look at mime types.